# How to make customer to use the Paypal in the checkout page, not actual paypal page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new in Woocommerce and want to know if there is a feature for this:
When customer add the product to the cart and try to check out, they mostly click the Paypal method to pay.
But when they click Paypal method to pay, the checkout page directly transfer to Paypal page.
So, I want to make my site that customer can easily use paypal in the checkout page, not transfer to the actual Paypal page.
Is there any way I can do that?

Thanks,

Comment: Please go read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). And for your question, read [PayPal Extension Comparison](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/paypal-extension-comparison/)

Answer (score 0):

You likely need a different PayPal extension (like PayPal Pro) for WooCommerce.

See the "Keep Customers On Your Site" options on the [PayPal Extension Comparison](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/paypal-extension-comparison/)